# How can I add dark matter to my $N$-body simulation?

Tags: gravity, simulations, dark-matter, many-body, galaxy-rotation-curve

I've written a simple non-scientific N-body simulation for fun:
http://magwo.github.io/fullofstars/

I expected to create something looking like spinning galaxies (there are two invisible very heavy objects in that simulation).

However, as I learned, for it to resemble galaxies there needs to be something more than just $N$-body simulation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_rotation_curve

So my question is this: **For my simulation to look like spinning galaxies, how should the dark matter be positioned, moving, and how should it interact with the visible particles?**

Should the dark matter be at all affected by the gravity of the visible particles? Or should it be a one-way interaction? What makes the dark matter stay "in place" to preserve its "compressing" effect on the particle cloud? Is the gravity interaction from the dark matter an attraction force just like normal gravity, or is it a repelling force?

Comment: Whoa!!! How many questions are you really asking? You have three followed by another five. No offence intended,  but would you consider splitting them up? Better chance of getting answers that way. Have you read this? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter  Regards

Comment: Hehe well! The followup questions are more like specific clarifying questions of the main question. Yes I've skimmed the wikipedia article but wasn't able to find any specific proposals for how dark matter interacts with regular matter, and especially, if it is affected by regular matter in the same way as regular matter is affected by other regular matter.

Comment: Hi Magnus, I don't think it works like that. Some of your questions are complicated, for them to be answered properly, so you can model things accurately, will take time.  Search this site, there may be answers here already. Best of luck with it though.

Comment: What do your normal matter particles do other than gravitate? If the answer is "nothing," then they are not terribly different from dark matter. On large scales where everything is like a fluid, the only difference between dark and normal matter is that the dark matter is pressureless.

Comment: @ChrisWhite ok nice.

But I fail to understand how normal gravity can achieve the "compression" effect needed for high-velocity high-altitude stars to not escape the galaxy fairly quickly. Surely, adding more mass is not the answer, as that would also increase the gravity on the inner stars, requiring them to move much faster. And a realistic galaxy rotation would then not be achieved.

Edit: and yes, the particles do not do anything except attract each other.

Comment: Magnus, did you understand what @Chris said when he asked about the behaviors of the particles in your simulation and about dark matter being pressureless? This is important because a naive simulation based on $N$ gravitating but otherwise non-interacting particles simply doesn't include all the right physics of the ordinary matter. Other question for you: have you validated the physics-engine on 2-body runs? Have you done so in runs that include very close encounters (so that the duration of close approach is less than a time-step? Possible alternate site: [scicomp.se].

Comment: @dmckee Thanks for your reply! Does pressure and non-gravitational interaction of regular matter really matter much in galaxy simulations where each star is a single particle? I've always assumed that anything but gravity is neglible on this scale, where so much "empty" space exists between the stars.

Comment: And no, I have not validated it. As you point out, it is very possible that close interactions occur during less than a time step, causing incorrect introduction or reduction of energy (I think). This is what causes the little explosions where stars fly away at high speed. It is a problem and I would like to fix it, but I _think_ it does not affect the discussion at hand, since for the most part the particle cloud behaves somewhat correctly with regards to newtonian gravity.

Comment: The fact that the density profile of the regular matter and that of the dark matter differ shows explicitly that the differences in physics are important. The effects are small, but they work inexorable and continuously in the same direction so the differences build up over time.

Comment: @dmckee is it the pressure interactions (dark matter with regular matter?) that causes the dark matter to end up in a halo around the galaxy? If not, why is the dark matter in a halo formation?

Comment: @dmckee Um.. are we talking radiation pressure here?

Comment: A good starting point would be look at the [Gadget-2 paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005MNRAS.364.1105S) and citations thereof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your question, and after watching your simulation, it seems that you actually *only* have dark matter (DM) in your simulation. An N-body code simulates DM, i.e. particles that interact only by gravitation. If you want to take it a step further, you want to include *gas*, i.e. particles that interact both by gravitation and by hydrodynamics.

This is not trivial, but the basic idea is that when gas particles get close enough, they build up pressure, are slowed down by viscosity forces, experience turbulence, heat up and lose energy through radiation, etc. If a region becomes sufficiently dense, it may form stars, which in turn heat up the gas again.

When a code is particle-based (as opposed to grid-based), this is called [smoothed particle hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) (SPH).

However, I think you can start by doing something more simple. I may be wrong, but from looking at your simulation, it seems to me that you are calculating gravitational forces between particle $i$ and particle $j$ through
$$
F_{ij} = \frac{m_i m_j}{r_{ij}^2}, \qquad\qquad(\mathrm{correct \, in \, real \, life})
$$
which of course in principle is correct. However, in numerical simulations, due to finite step sizes and floating point precision, particles easily come to close, resulting in diverging forces, which tend to sling out particles with unnaturally high velocities. For this reason, people use a so-called [gravitational softening length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softening) $\varepsilon$, such that the force between the particles become
$$
F_{ij} = \frac{m_i m_j}{r_{ij}^2 + \varepsilon^2} \qquad\qquad(\mathrm{correct \, in \, simulations}).
$$
The optimal value of $\varepsilon$ is a matter of choice. You may want to try different values, but it should be of the order of (or a little smaller than) the mean distance between particles in the regions you want to resolve. Your time steps should also be adapted to this, so that particles on average don't travel more than $\varepsilon/2$ per timestep (e.g. [Rodionov & Sotnikova 2005](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005ARep...49..470R)). For instance, try and start by setting $\varepsilon = L/100$, where $L$ is the length of your box.

Including this parameter should make your DM particles clump more. However, if you want beautiful spiral patterns, you have to include gas.

Comment: I think that the softening of the newtonian force is a zero-order kind of regularization. It is pretty easy to implement and simple to grasp, but I don't see how one can estimate how good this approximation is. I think the "matter of choice" argument is good enough for non-physical "nice-to-see" application, but is of course of no help if one is concerned with real physics.

Comment: @sintetico: There are ways of estimating an optimal $\varepsilon$. For instance you can argue that it should be high enough to prevent divergence, but low enough that it affects test benchmark results only to within some chosen tolerance. Plenty of authors that do real physics has delved into this, e.g. [these](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006ApJ...639..617Z), [these](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013MNRAS.436.1161I), and [these](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2007MNRAS.374.1347P).

Comment: So, if I am right, corrections are evaluated by a confrontation between known "benchmark". This is a kind of euristic, but how can one be sure that the approximation will work also in the general case. I mean, is there a way to estimate the correction? Also consider that in most of the cases gravitational systems are chaotic, which means that a small computational error or approximation can have huge effects on the outcome. Please consider that I am not an expert on this problem, and that I am just curious on this problem.

Comment: I mean, your "softening" method is much better than regularization, because is much simpler. So can one use the "softening" in any case? Are there caveats to consider to apply this method?

Comment: @sintetico: To be honest, I had never heard about this _regularization technique_. I just talked to some colleagues, and neither had they. I think that gravitational softening is by far the most used technique.

Comment: As for the reliability, any numerical approximation — of which there are _plenty_ in an N-body simulation and most other simulations as well — introduces uncertainties. But in addition to testing, your code must at least to some extend agree with various observables. For instance for a cosmological simulation, you can check your simulated galaxies against observed number densities, morphologies, colors, mass distributions, etc.

Comment: I agree, but for any numerical approximation it should be possible to estimate the error, even roughly. I am just curious how this can be done in this case.

Comment: Well, definitely not all approximation effects are well-understood. For instance, before implementing stellar feedback in hydrosimulations, I don't think people had any idea of all the implications for this. But what you can say about $\epsilon$ is that a given simulation has a certain spatial resolution. That is, you shouldn't trust effects on spatial scales smaller than $\epsilon$ (unless you implement _subgrid physics_). For instance, if you are interested in density profiles of dark matter halos, $\epsilon$ will be a lower threshold on _how_ central you can probe the profile.

Comment: Thanks! I've started to experiment with this softening addition, and it does seem healthy for the stability.

Comment: Using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plummer_model which seems to be the same thing.

Comment: @MagnusWolffelt: I think the Plummer model is a slightly different approach that may be fine for toy models, but not for scientific purposes, but the idea is the same, and since your model _is_ a toy model, all is good :)

Comment: @pela The Plummer model looks to me _exactly_ like the technique you described (look at the potential...). Correct me please if I am wrong.

Comment: @sintetico: I guess you're right, I hadn't used this name before. Another approach, that some argue (e.g. Hernquist & Katz 1989,) is better, is a spline kernel

Comment: I am not an expert, and Wikipedia may be wrong, but it seems that the Plummer model is regarded as a toy model there.

Comment: @sintetico: Okay, I had a closer look, and the Plummer model is _not_ the same as "mine" (in lack of a better name). The Plummer model, having $F\propto r/(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{3/2}$, increases for $r\rightarrow0$, but then decreases for very small $r$, ending at zero for $r=0$. In contrast, "my" model, having $F\propto1/(r^2+\epsilon^2)$, increases for $r\rightarrow0$ but ends at a finite value.

Comment: Cool. Actually I was curious because "your model" looks easy to implement and avoids the divergence problem of $F\propto r^{-2}$. If it is used in literature, then I think it is good enough for serious calculations (not just toy models).

Comment: Yes, it's quite popular for scientific calculations. Btw, @MagnusWolffelt if you haven't already seen the last handful of comments on the difference between the two models, you may be interested in looking into the difference.

Comment: Thanks! I've read the discussion, and will probably use the one you suggest @pela.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Acid Jazz is correct in every point, in my opinion. However, I think that the problem in your simulations is not dark matter, but something more subtle. Perhaps I oversimplify here, but dark matter will behave in your model exactly like normal matter, with the exception of being *dark*, not visible. It is in fact exactly the case of the two invisible objects of your simulation. In fact, you are *already* considering two dark matter halos in the simulation.

For what I see, in your simulation the "stars" are accelerated and expelled at huge speeds after that they experience a *close encounter* with another star (or with one of the invisible objects). I presume that you are solving directly and separately the dynamics of each of these star, taking into account the mutual attraction. However, the newtonian potential has a singularity when two masses approach at short distance $r\approx0$ (the attraction is proportional to $r^{-2}$). This constitutes a computational problem in gravitational simulations, and is probably why you see these anomalies in your simulation, which prevent the emergence of large scale structures, like galaxies.  A method to deal with this problem is known as **Regularization** (although I think it is not the only method).

I am not an expert in the field, I just found this link that seems to be a useful introduction to non-experts: 
[Basics of regularization theory](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/e/03-547.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess for these questions: (but I am no expert so it's a **guess**, right?)

> Should the dark matter be at all affected by the gravity of the visible particles?

Yes

> Or should it be a one-way interaction?

No, gravity should act equally on visible and dark matter.

> What makes the dark matter stay "in place" to preserve its "compressing" effect on the particle cloud?

Normal gravity probably (open to correction though), I am not exactly sure what else you mean, it is distributed  in a halo around galaxies but extends much further out than visible matter. Also, it may be distributed  in filaments and clumps without any visible matter nearby.

> Is the gravity interaction from the dark matter an attraction force just like normal gravity, or is it a repelling force?

Attractive only

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This clarifies some things. However, if the dark matter interacts with regular matter just like regular matter (if more weakly), then what makes it stay in this halo distribution around the galaxy? It seems like some sort of pressure/buoyancy effect is in place, no?

Comment: angular momentum

Comment: And also, if the dark matter is in a halo around the galaxy, with attractive force, why is the speed of high-altitude stars so unexpectedly high? If anything, there needs to be a force pushing these high-velocity, high-altitude stars into the galaxy rather than attracting them out of it.

Comment: See what I mean, it's  complicated :) so set them up as individual questions  if you need to, but you are getting there.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a few small gravity simulations, and I would bet that the problem is that the particles aren't colliding. I know this doesn't answer your original question, but I think that's the answer to fixing your simulation.